# Can I mount a partition from a full drive image?

Tags: mount, dd

Note: While I agree that this question basically is a duplicate of the above question, I feel @alienth's answer (below) is more concise, so I suggest you take a look at it before going to the other question.

I periodically backup/image/clone my entire ubuntu system drive to another drive with:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/media/disk1/backup.iso
```

It works great when I need to restore the drive after an experiment, drive failure, etc.

However I'd now like to mount a partition from within that .iso (i.e. what would have been /dev/sda1 when I was dd'ing the drive).  If I'd backed up with:

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/media/disk1/backup.iso
```

then the .iso would be easily mountable using ubuntu's mount volume utility.  But the utility doesn't work for an iso of the entire drive.  Is there a way to just mount sda1 from the original iso?

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?q=mount%20partition%20of%20disk%20image => http://madduck.net/blog/2006.10.20:loop-mounting-partitions-from-a-disk-image/

Comment: One notable issue with that blog post is that it uses `fdisk`, which may not work correctly with a GPT partition table (which is the standard on many recent distro releases).

Comment: You're aware that although you've used the suffix `.iso`, your image isn't actually an [ISO image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660), it's a raw disk image?

Comment: I knew that I was creating a raw disk image, and now that I think about it I do remember someone explaining that an iso is some sort of concatenation of files, so I guess I *should* have been aware.  I am now, anyway - thanks.

Comment: See the answers to this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/69363/mount-single-partition-from-image-of-entire-disk-device

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need to determine where in the disk image your partition starts. To do so, run the following:

`sudo parted /media/disk1/backup.iso unit s print`

The output will look like the following:

```
Model:  (file)
Disk /tmp/file: 200000s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start  End      Size     Type     File system  Flags
 1      2048s  199999s  197952s  primary
```

You need to take the logical sector size and multiply that by the `Start` of the partition you'd like to mount. In this case, if I want to mount the first partition, the position would be `2048 * 512`, or `1048576`.

You can then mount the partition using a loopback setup, plugging the value determined from above into the `offset` parameter.

`mount -o loop,offset=1048576 /media/disk1/backup.iso /mnt/mydisk`

Comment: Very helpful indeed!  If you are trying to mount an lvm partition, you should follow [these directions](http://www.utilities-online.info/articles/Mount-an-LVM-partition-image-cloned-with-dd/#.Wf0MzXBrxGo), but you will need to use the offset as shown in this answer.  So instead of `losetup /dev/loop0 backup-cloud.img`, you need `losetup -o XXX` where `XXX` is the offset computed as shown above (start * 512, assuming logical/physical is 512).

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to see a partition table within a full-disk image. Two, in fact.

The first way:

```
# losetup /dev/loop0 /media/disk1/backup.iso
# fdisk /dev/loop0 # Be very careful with this!
Command: w
```

This should, ideally, create loop devices `/dev/loop0p1`, `/dev/loop0p2` and so forth for the partitions in `backup.iso`. You can then mount these normally as loop devices; it's probably prudent to do it read-only, so as not to corrupt your backup. There are likely safer ways to trigger the partition read than using `fdisk` directly, such as `partprobe` or `kpartx`; however, I've had reliability issues with those, and `fdisk` is the best way I've found.

The second way is more difficult. It involves reading the partition start manually (`fdisk -l /dev/loop0`), then redoing `losetup` with an appropriate `--offset` option to make the loop device begin at the partition start. Precisely what number you pass depends on the output from `fdisk`, but it's an offset in bytes, equal to the starting block times the block size. At that point, you can mount `/dev/loop0` directly (again, read-only is prudent).

Comment: This assumes that his disk image isn't in GPT format. `parted` would handle it either way, so is likely preferable.

Comment: Recent `fdisk` can handle GPT, I thought? Don't know if it's part of the default `-l` output, though. If you're doing the manual-offset method, you're likely correct.

Comment: I'm on a recent Mint release and `fdisk` bombs with a warning about GPT and spits out an incorrect partition layout. Using version 2.20.1.

Comment: Also, curiously I can't get `loop0p1` to show up in a test case by simply writing out the partition table with `fdisk` (with a standard DOS-type table), despite it being listed when printed out with `fdisk`. I do know that used to work. `partprobe` doesn't fetch it, either.

Comment: Huh. Historically I've had intermittent success with `partprobe` and reliable success with `fdisk`. `kpartx`, maybe?

Comment: Same result. Very weird! `kpartx -av` does spit out the `loop0p1` partition, but a device mapping isn't created. This is on Mint 17.1 (aka Ubuntu 14.04). I wonder what changed to make this not work?

Comment: I've tested mostly on eccentric custom systems, but they've certainly had modern kernels and userlands. Ubuntu being odd, maybe?

Comment: @Tom Hunt: `gdisk` is for GPT things; `fdisk` only got GPT support in 
Util-linux 2.24, which may not have tricked down yet (it's not in centos7).

Comment: You can use the `-P` option to requst a partition scan of the created loop device - this is what sets up the partition device nodes. I often use it like this: `dev=$(sudo losetup -P -f --show disk.img)` and then I can do `sudo mount ${dev}p2 /mnt`, cleaning up afterwards with `sudo losetup -d $dev`.